# Is there a specific reason why FFMPEG does not support loading of external filter?

Tags: ffmpeg

As above:

Is there a specific reason why FFMPEG does not support loading of external filter without a 3rd part libray? (Like Frei0r)
I have to recompile the whole package to add a new filter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the devs can definitely answer but I would venture security risks and the API conservation imposed by public runtime use.

But the relevant devs are open to it.

From https://www.mail-archive.com/ffmpeg-devel@ffmpeg.org/msg44592.html

> Right now, because a not of necessary structures and functions are
>   internal, plugins are not possible, so this patch is not making things
>   any worse. I am all in favour of allowing plugins eventually, but I
>   think the only reasonable course of action is: first a good API, then
>   make it stable, then make it public.